# How to add dynamic commentary in less?

Tags: less, comments

How to make the review itself was written?

```
.className {
    some style...

    // .className .children (how to write this comments?)
   .children {
       some style...
   }
}
```

Comment: Hi @jsp , welcome to SO or sort of ... Can you give us more insights about the context , what you have tried and what kind of results you are looking for? For any future questions you will have , please read this post . It will surely help you http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/

Comment: I once met an article about how it can be done, but I can't find it now. And how to implement have no idea that asked the question, can someone tell me...

Answer (score 0):

If you want that comment will be visible after LESS compilation as a simple CSS comment, simply replace `//` (*LESS single row comment*) with `/*...*/` (*CSS comment*). Probably you have to move it down into the relative rule, to be sure that is placed near it. So:

```
.className {
    some style...

   .children {
       /* .className .children (how to write this comments?) */
       some style...
   }
}
```

Please note that *this is the default behaviour if final code will not minified* (minification strips all comments, LESS and CSS ones).

Final code:

```
.className {
  some style... 
}

.className .children {
  /* .className .children (how to write this comments?) */
  some style...
}
```

Comment: I want comments to be automatically generated. The fact that you can use /* */, I know

Comment: @jsp "automatically" - you'd better to put that into the Q (but then it becomes a "searching for a tool" question and goes offtopic at SO).